# Xcode 12 AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Looks like the "corners" property of AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject is somehow missing using Xcode 12.

It is still mentioned in the documentation but the compiler fails with

```
"Value of type 'AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject' has no member 'corners'".
```

I am importing AVFoundation

Comment: Seems to be a bug with the Xcode 12 toolchain. Also being discussed here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/658471

Answer (score 12):

This is currently a bug from what I can tell and was in the beta, try using #if !targetEnvironment(simulator) as that worked for people in the beta.

Edit:
This was also a problem in other versions of Xcode with the same fix, and may also be a problem in Xcode 13 as well, just a heads up.

Comment: This worked fantastically. Since the introduction of targetEnvironment, Apple team most be probably limiting the existence of some properties according to their running context/environment. (This is just speculation, because I have nothing to base this argument, only that my build compiled fine for simulator and for device using this #if compiler flag)

Comment: Glad it worked! When you have time could you accept my answer please.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the XCode bug has been **fixed in XCode 12.1**.